# why can't you add matrices of different sizes?

Tags: matrices

Why can't matrices of different shapes be added together? For example if you have these 3 equations:

```
x+y=1
x+y=1
```

and

```
x+y+z=3
```

the corresponding coefficient matrices are

```
⎡1 1⎤
⎣1 1⎦   

⎡     ⎤
|1 1 1|
⎣     ⎦
```

You can easily add the equations (first with the first one and second with the second one) to produce

```
2x+2y+z=4
2x+2y+z=4
```

, but you cant add matrices to produce

```
  ⎡2 2 1⎤
  ⎣2 2 1⎦
```

Why? I picked the equations randomly. I am  aware of the rules, I just don't know why are they are as they are.

Comment: I think the primary reason is that a matrix has no sense of the intended variables behind it.  You can apply an interpretation of a given matrix that allows this kind of addition, but that interpretation is specific to some goal you have and not a natural property of matrices...

Comment: Actually, your first matrix should be $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: You only have two equations. Still, though, given those two equations above, what you really have is $x+y+z=1+z=3 \implies z=2$ so you don't really have $4$ equations above. Anyway, the purpose of not being able to add them is that matrices live in *spaces* of certain dimensions, these dimensions need to be equal in order to add them, not necessary so with multiplying them, however.

Comment: They can't be added because they were not "defined" so.Once Matrix addition is a "definition", there is no questioning it. You may question the theorems evolving but not the definition.

Comment: @BijeshK.S Couldn't we give a definition for adding matrices of different size? E.g. I can define that operation. Suppose two matrices A (3x3) and B (2x3). AB would be a matrix where the two rows of B are beneath the rows of A. To define or not define is not an arbitrary choice. It follows naturally by the axioms.